# How do I speed up an animation while it is already occurring using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimation

I'm new to UI programming and right now I'm trying to make the screen pulse at a speed based on the number of times the screen has been tapped. My issue is that when a tap is detected and the duration of the animation is shortened, it starts the animation from the beginning creating a white flash as it restarts. How would I go about speeding up the animation from whatever point it is at when a tap is detected.

My Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var tapCount: Int = 0
    var pulseSpeed: Double = 3

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        counter.center = CGPoint(x: 185, y: 118)

        pulseAnimation(pulseSpeed: pulseSpeed)
    }

    func pulseAnimation(pulseSpeed: Double) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: pulseSpeed, delay: 0, options:   [UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.autoreverse],
        animations: {
            self.red.alpha = 0.5
            self.red.alpha = 1.0
        })
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var red: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var counter: UILabel!

    @IBAction func screenTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        tapCount += 1
        counter.text = "\(tapCount)"
        pulseSpeed = Double(3) / Double(tapCount)
        pulseAnimation(pulseSpeed: pulseSpeed)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Core Animation directly to achieve what you're after instead of relying on the `UIView` animation which is built in top.

```
// create animation in viewDidLoad
let pulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
pulseAnimation.fromValue = 0.5
pulseAnimation.toValue = 1.0
pulseAnimation.autoreverses = true
pulseAnimation.duration = 3.0
pulseAnimation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude

// save animation to property on ViewController
self.pulseAnimation = pulseAnimation

// update animation speed in screenTapButton
pulseAnimation.speed += 0.5
```

You may want to play with the speed numbers a little. The default speed is 1.0 and the animation specifies a duration of 3 seconds, so it should take 6 seconds to go from 0.5 to 1.0 back to 0.5. At a speed of 2.0, the same animation will happen twice as quickly, or 3 seconds for the full cycle.

I hope that helps!